# Open Facebook app share dialog from mobile web link

Tags: facebook, applinks

I'm trying to open a share dialog in the native Facebook app (Android & iOS) from a mobile web page. I am handling the possibility that the user will not have the app installed so that's not an issue. I was hoping to open the native app using something like `window.open("fb://sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.link.com", "sharer", "toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=500");` this does open the app but does not open the share dialog. I've found a number of previous answers stating that it's not possible but they were a couple of years old so I decided to post the question again in the hope that someone knows of a way to achieve this.

Comment: Facebook doesn't have any supported deep links

Comment: What about unsupported? I found a list of unsupported links but it did not containing a share link, but again it was quite old so I wondered if it had been implemented since.